# Android Studio - searching for a line in the entire package

Tags: android

How can i search for a line of code in the entire project/package ?
I have an error which i cannot find, the monitor tells me where the problem is 
but i need to find the place that calls this problem line, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `Ctrl + Shift + F`, It will pop up a window, put your code there, then click find.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error giving you line number? If so, you can use `Go to line` Command

Go to line 10
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>10</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>